# get current hard disk read write in ubuntu and make log file

Tags: 13.04, server

I'm writing a customized monitoring panel for Ubuntu Server.

At this step I need to get real time hard disk read and write rate then put it into a file as a log file.

I used tools like Hdparm, Iotop but they did not work. I want the result in a file.

I want a result such as:  `10Kb read - 2kb write - 2014-2-13 16:40:03`

So I can run it as Crontab and monitor every I/O rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iostat.

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

Ex:

```
iostat -d 2 /dev/sda
```